# Quine Challenge I

Tags: code-golf, quine

### Challenge

> In this task you have to write a program that will take input
>   an integer N **(-1e9 <= N < 0 && 0 < N
>   <= +1e9)**, then compute **T = (abs(N) %
>   M+1)**,if N is positive then output
>   the T-th character from the
>   beginning else output the T-th
>   character from the end of your source.
>
> **M is the size of your source in bytes.**

**Example:** If your source is: `abcd efg/hi`

**Input:**

```
 2
```

**Output:**

```
 c
```

**Input**:

```
-3
```

**Output:**

```
g
```

**Input**:

```
-9249678
```

**Output:**

```
b
```

**Input**:

```
-11
```

**Output:**

```
i
```

**Constraints**

- Don't use any FILE operation
- You can use any language of your choice
- Try to avoid or rather don't use 1 byte submissions, since it spoils all fun.
- Shortest solution wins!

> **EDIT:** Problem statement have been modified so that the solutions could be
>   judged using a random test-data (and
>   same data for all solutions) hence
>   please update your solution
>   accordingly,sorry for the inconvenience
>   (if any).

Comment: In the give example test case if the input is **5** or **-7** the output should be a single space : " " (without quotation).

Comment: What if N is 0?

Comment: @eBusiness:Thanks for pointing that out, I have changed the problem statement,I don't think $0$ can occur now :-)

Comment: @Debanjan: your edit makes the case where N=M+1 a little weird.

Comment: Opertor precedence `%M` will be executed first before addition ;-)

Comment: @Debanjan: oh I see.  The spacing got me.

Comment: Your examples don't match your challenge description, if I'm not completely mistaken. First example: `N=2`, so `T=3`. The 3rd character is `c`, not `b`.

Comment: @Ventero:Yes,thanks for pointing,I fixed it now.

Comment: It sorta keeps on being a strange mapping, now a character is skipped at the jump from 0 to 1: `-2 -> /` `-1 -> h` `0 -> i` `1 -> b` `2 -> c`. But at least the mapping is now unanimous.

Comment: I guess the `&&` in the first sentence is meant to be a `||`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### x86 assembly (32-bit Linux, AT&T syntax): 548

No newline at end of file:

```
pushl 8(%esp)
call atoi
mov $274,%ebx
cmp $0,%eax
jg a
dec %eax
a:cdq
idiv %ebx
cmp $0,%edx
jge p
add %ebx,%edx
p:add $s,%edx
cmp $s+273,%edx
jl l
push $34
mov %esp,%edx
l:mov $4,%eax
mov $1,%ebx
mov %edx,%ecx
mov $1,%edx
int $128
mov $0,%ebx
mov $1,%eax
int $128
s:.ascii "pushl 8(%esp)
call atoi
mov $274,%ebx
cmp $0,%eax
jg a
dec %eax
a:cdq
idiv %ebx
cmp $0,%edx
jge p
add %ebx,%edx
p:add $s,%edx
cmp $s+273,%edx
jl l
push $34
mov %esp,%edx
l:mov $4,%eax
mov $1,%ebx
mov %edx,%ecx
mov $1,%edx
int $128
mov $0,%ebx
mov $1,%eax
int $128
s:.ascii "
```

I compiled it with `gcc -nostartfiles -m32 qc1.S -o qc1`

Verification, positive numbers:

```
$ for i in $(seq 548 1095); do ./qc1 $i; done | cmp - qc1.S && echo Good
Good
```

Verification, negative numbers:

```
$ for i in $(seq -1095 -548); do ./qc1 $i; done | cmp - qc1.S && echo Good
Good
```

**Edit** got it right about the weird numbering scheme.  *I think.*  It didn't change the length.

Comment: +1,That's brilliant work to do this in assembly,but one small thing I have modified the problem to make testing unanimous so please modify your solution like-wise, Thanks.

Comment: Heh, pretty cool. And a funny thing, despite being so different languages this does seem to resemble my 44 characters GolfScript solution.

Comment: @Debanjan: I really can't seem to be able to wrap my head around the numbering scheme.  Could you provide the proper verification lines? (the problem statement would be a fine place)

Comment: +1, that's your second "invalid" asnwer here (code-golf wise) that worths upvoting :)

Comment: @Eelvex: for the record, the other one was valid at the time it was posted.

Comment: @Eelvex: there you go, this one's now totally valid.  Perhaps a bit long, though O:-)

Answer (score 10):

Whaddaya know, **HQ9+** makes its great return!

```
Q
```

No need to bother indexing when there's only one character to choose from!

Comment: Does it take any input?

Comment: @Debanjan: sure: `echo '-1' | hq9+ qc1`

Comment: Sorry,this is not making much sense to me,I have one similar solution in [PHP](http://ideone.com/QsqbA) but ain't this types of solution spoils all the fun? Thanks,

Comment: You don't *have* to accept it if you don't think it fits in, you know!  You don't even have to upvote it.  You may even downvote it, though *I*'d personally not appreciate ;-)

Comment: No,It's not about acceptation or rejection,I was just stating a point also I would like up-vote it since I learn something new :-)

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby 1.9, 66 characters

```
z=gets.to_i;s="z=gets.to_i;s=%p;$><<(s%%s)[z%%66]";$><<(s%s)[z%66]
```

Not much difference to a normal quine, actually.

- Edit: Follows the new specs now.

Answer (score 5):

## GolfScript 26 characters

```
{':f`f'+1/\~.1<- 26%=}:f`f
```

Quines were more fun before the invention of dynamic languages.

Edit: For the whiners, here is a "real" GolfScript quine, no ` and ~ only used for parsing the input.

## Handicapped GolfScript 44 characters

```
'"\x27"\+1/\~.1<- 22%='"\x27"\+1/\~.1<- 22%=
```

Notice how nicely it is the same string repeated twice, so the string literal just need a `'` hacked in front of it and it's ready for use.

Comment: I don't know GolfScript, but your comment pushes me to think your code leans towards the "FILE operation" category of constraints.  Care to expand its innards?

Comment: The magic happens by the use of the ` operator, basically I define a function, store it in a variable, convert the function to it's own string representation (` does that), and then I run the function, which can trivially finish the task as it has it's own innards in the string.

Comment: +1: to `Quines were more fun before the invention of dynamic languages.` :-)

Comment: Well I sure as hell wouldn't be trying *this* one in assembly language...

Comment: @J B:This is great fun in C,I did something like this recently :-)

Comment: Ok, maybe I'll give it a shot.  Just not this week.

Comment: I think I'm 100 years behind you people :(

Comment: Scratch that. I *did* try this one in assembly language.

Answer (score 2):

## Lenguage, 4 bytes

Source code consists of 4 null bytes. Regardless of the input, the output should thus be a null byte, which is accomplished by one `.` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

## Smalltalk, <strike>94 90 59</strike> 52

for example, in the Object class, compile:

```
q:n|s|s:=thisContext method source.^s at:n\\s size+1
```

then send q:<n> to any object; here an integer:

verification:

1 q:0 -> q
1 q:1 -> :
1 q:2 -> n
...
1 q:-1 -> )
1 q:-2 -> )
1 q:-3 -> 1

or better:
(0 to:100) collect:[:n|1 q:n]as:String
-> `')q:n|s m|s:=thisContext method source.m:=s size.^s at:(n>=0ifTrue:n-1\\m+1ifFalse:m-(0-n\\m))q:n|s m|'`

(-1 downTo:-500)collect:[:n|1 q:n]as:String
-> `')m\\n-0(-m:eslaFfi1+m\\1-n:eurTfi0=>n(:ta s^.ezis s=:m.ecruos dohtem txetnoCsiht=:s|m s|n:q))m\\n-0('`

explanation for non-Smalltalkers:
*thisContext* is the current stack frame, which can be asked for its *method*, which can be asked for its *source*.

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 17 bytes

```
"3X4+kSq:l͍iS%%@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/1/JOMJEOzu40CrnbG9msKqqw///ukamAA)

Just uses standard quine to generate the program string, then uses string-based modulo operator<sup>1</sup> to get the character at a given index (which natively support negative and positive indicies, behavior influenced by Python).

1. <sub>The `,` "divide" command cuts the string up into chunks (logical enough inverse of `*` duplicating the string `x` times), `+` concatenates, and `-` removes `x` characters from the end (a logical enough inverse of `+`). So the `%` command takes the role of `charAt(x)`: the only basic string operation remaining (after stack-like operations being handled by the same commands that deal with the stack; eg. `l` is the size of the stack so `l͍` is the length of a string).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

```
f=n=>("f="+f).substr(n%28,1)
```

A modified quine.

A value larger than 28 is handled by `%28`, a value less than 0 is handled by `.substr()`.