# Golf a mutual quine

Tags: code-golf, quine, polyglot

Using *two* languages of your choice, write the smallest “mutual [quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29)” you can.

That is, write a program P in language A that outputs the source code for a program Q in language B, such that the output of program Q is identical to the source code for P.

Empty files don't count, nor do "read the source file and print it"-style programs.

**Edit:** Answers with P=Q no longer count.

Comment: Btw, this should preclude cases where the sources match. For example `1` is a quine in several languages. So you could say its a J program that prints a Golfscript program that prints a...... and so on.

Comment: you can adopt the rule of "Try to avoid or rather don't use 1 byte submissions like this one ,since it spoils all fun." from http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/code-golf-quine-challenge-i

Comment: A Brainfuck + Befunge solution should be posted.

Comment: Can language A = language B?

Comment: Since this is golf, can you clarify the scoring criteria? For example, is the final score the sum of the byte counts of P and Q? Or the minimum of the byte counts of P and Q?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish) and [APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 bytes and 13 bytes

```
'r3d*:::}H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/X73IOEXLysqq1uP/fwA) Which outputs:

```apl
'''r3d*:::}H'
```

[Try APL online!](https://tryapl.org/?a=%27%27%27r3d*%3A%3A%3A%7DH%27&run)

Which simple prints the code as a string (with the `'` escaped with another `'`)

Answer (score 34):

### Python and Ruby, 39 characters

This Python snippet

```
s='puts %%q{s=%r;print s%%s}';print s%s
```

generates this Ruby snippet

```
puts %q{s='puts %%q{s=%r;print s%%s}';print s%s}
```

which then generates the inital Python snippet again:

```
$ diff -s mutualquine.py <(ruby <(python mutualquine.py))
Files mutualquine.py and /dev/fd/63 are identical
```

Note that this is similar to [J B's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/golf-a-mutual-quine/2588#2588).

Answer (score 24):

### C and Perl, 73

This C:

```
main(s){printf(s="print q<main(s){printf(s=%c%s%c,34,s,34);}>",34,s,34);}
```

...outputs the following Perl:

```
print q<main(s){printf(s="print q<main(s){printf(s=%c%s%c,34,s,34);}>",34,s,34);}>
```

...that outputs the C back.

Comment: Save 4 bytes: `main(s){printf(s="print q<main(s){printf(s=%c%s%1$c,34,s);}>",34,s);}`

Answer (score 16):

## C and C++, 123 chars

This C (compilable with gcc v4.3.4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){char *c="#include <stdio.h>%cmain(){char *c=%c%s%c;printf(c,10,34,c,34);}";printf(c,10,34,c,34);}
```

outputs this (identical) C++ (compilable with g++ 4.3.4, one warning):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){char *c="#include <stdio.h>%cmain(){char *c=%c%s%c;printf(c,10,34,c,34);}";printf(c,10,34,c,34);}
```

*This is within the rules as posted.*  :P  And, like Ventero's, this is based on [J B's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/golf-a-mutual-quine/2588#2588).

Comment: OK, so it was within the rules as posted until the edit saying the sources can't be the same. A minor change could fix that, but I'm disinclined to encourage such late edits.

Answer (score 16):

## [><> (Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) and Python - 26 characters

```
"00gr00g:a9*2+$' tnirp'>o<
```

Generates this Python

```
print "\"00gr00g:a9*2+$' tnirp'>o<"
```

Comment: You have an issue with the ><> code because `"` and `'` enable string parsing, so the entire program is just pushed onto the stack and never displayed.

Comment: @Bass5098 That's precisely how the whole thing works. The first `"` enables string parsing. It reads.the whole program and then _wraps back around_ to.the first `"` and runs the program with itself on the stack

Comment: Fixed the issue in my interpreter.  Your ><> code outputs `print \00gr00g:a9*2+$' tnirp'>o<` after timing out.  I'm pretty sure this is because `g` copies the actual cell contents, but `o` outputs the ASCII version of the character, and `"` isnt a valid ASCII character code. http://ideone.com/kaM0r

Comment: @Bass5098 `"` is ASCII 34. Your interpreter must be off.

Answer (score 10):

**Python + Piet one-liners: 417 chars + <strike>7391</strike> 7107 executing codels**

This Python script produces a 7393 x 2 image; the rightmost 2x2 block of which is a "sentinel" which terminates the program; so I'm not counting those; and the second row is otherwise white.  I can probably golf the piet code down further by using addition/subtraction/multiplication chains instead of the naive binary algorithm... but I don't want to give away a solution to a future puzzle.

I'm not going to post the image here, because of its ridiculous dimensions.  If you want to see it, run the python code, and pipe the output to a .ppm file.  Then, convert the .ppm to a .gif, and run the output at [Rapapaing](http://www.rapapaing.com/blog/?page_id=6).  (alternately, use a non-web Piet interpreter that groks .ppm)

```
A='P=lambda A:reduce(lambda(D,H,B),P:(D[P/3:]+D[:P/3],H[P%3*2:]+H[:P%3*2],B+"".join("%i "%H[(D[0]/P)%2]for P in[1,2,4])),map(" A !        @    B".find,A),([1,3,2,6,4,5],[0,192,192,255,0,255],"P3 %i 2 255 "%(len(A)+2)))[2]+"255 "*4+"0 0 "+"255 "*len(A)*3+"255 0 0 "*2;B=lambda D:["@!%s","@@!%s!"][D%2]%B(D/2)if 1<D else"";print P("".join("A%sB"%B(ord(D))for D in"A=%s;exec A[:-13]"%`A`)+" ");exec A[:-13]';exec A[:-13]
```

*edit: golfed the piet a bit by reducing Hamming weight of variable names.*

**less golfed pre-quine**:

This is a previous version, before I realized I could make it a one-liner.  It's marginally easier to understand.  The function P translates a special instruction set into Piet; and the function p takes an integer and produces a sequence of instructions to create that integer on the stack.  I'm only using the instructions `=,+,:,|`, so this could probably be made more efficient... but I kinda like having a fullblown Piet compiler (of sorts) in the source.

```
s="""def P(s):
 l=len(s)+1;R="P3 %i 2 255 "%(l+2);C=[1,3,2,6,4,5];V=[0,192,192,255,0,255]
 for x in map("=|^+-*/%~>.,:@$?#!".find,"="+s):
  C=C[x//3:]+C[:x//3];V=V[x%3*2:]+V[:x%3*2]
  for i in [1,2,4]:R+="%i "%V[(C[0]//i)%2]
 return R+"255 "*4+"0 0 "+"255 "*l*3+"255 0 0 "*2
p=lambda x:[":+%s","::+%s+"][x%2]%p(x/2)if x/2 else""
print P("".join("|%s!"%k(ord(c))for c in "s="+`s`+";exec s[:-13]"))
exec s[:-13]"""
exec s[:-13]
```

Comment: [Piet Creator](https://github.com/Ramblurr/PietCreator/wiki) is a much nicer (and far less buggy) Piet IDE. Written by [a user of this site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1375/casey), by the way :)

Comment: I've used Piet Creator before; it's a great tool.  Rapapaing is nice for people who are lazy, like me, and don't want to bother.  FWIW, I'd use Piet Creator if you ran it through http://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki, and put that up on your page.

Comment: I couldn't even get the Qt version to compile here ;)

Comment: ;) Thanks for trying, anyway.  I wrote you a fuzz tester: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2922/generate-a-random-program-in-your-favorite-language/3226#3226

Comment: Well, you could poke Casey in chat and point him to it ;-)

Answer (score 10):

## Java to Python - 219

Java:

```
class Q{public static void main(String[]a){char q=34,c=39;String s="print%sclass Q{public static void main(String[]a){char q=34,c=39;String s=%s%s%s;System.out.printf(s,c,q,s,q,c);}}%s";System.out.printf(s,c,q,s,q,c);}}
```

Python:

```
print'class Q{public static void main(String[]a){char q=34,c=39;String s="print%sclass Q{public static void main(String[]a){char q=34,c=39;String s=%s%s%s;System.out.printf(s,c,q,s,q,c);}}%s";System.out.printf(s,c,q,s,q,c);}}'
```

Makes use of the fact that python allows `'` for strings; this makes it much easier to write the java program's source in the python program.

Comment: +1 for doing the dirty work in the worst golfing language ever. :P

Answer (score 8):

## /Brainf..k/, 6988 bytes

### Brainfuck

```
++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++>>>+++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>+++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++>>>+>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>+>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>+++++++++>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>++>>>++>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++>>>+++++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>+>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>+++++++++>>>++>>>++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>+++++++++>>>++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++>>>+>>>++>>>+++++++++>>>++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>+>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>+>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>++>>>++++++++++>>>++++++>>>++++++>>>++++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++>>>++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++++>>>++++++>>>++++++++>>>++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++>>>+++>>>+++++>>>++++>>>+++++++>>>+++>>>++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++>>>+++++>>>++++++++>>>++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++++>>>++++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++>>>++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++++++>>>++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+++++++>>>++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++++++>>>++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++++++>>>++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+++++++>>>++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++++++>>>++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++++++>>>++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++++++>>>++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++++++>>>++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++++++>>>++++>>>++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++>>>+++>>>+++++++>>>++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++>>>+++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++++++>>>+++++++++++>>>++++++>>>+++++++>>>{({}<>)<>}<>{([({})]()<((((()()()()()){}){}){})>){({}()<({}())>){({}()<({}()())>){({}()<({}()())>){({}()<({}())>){({}()<({}((()()()){}()){})>){({}()<({}()())>){({}()<({}(((()()()){}()){}){}())>){({}()<({}()())>){({}()<({}(((()()()()())){}{}){})>){(<{}({}()())>)}}}}}}}}}}{}({}<(<>)<>{({}<>)<>}{}>)(<><>)<>{({}<>)<>}{}<>{({}[()])<>(((((()()()){}())){}{}){}())<>}{}<>(((({})(((()()())){}{}){}())))<>}{}([]){((({}[()])<{({}[()]<({}<({}<>)<>>)>)}{}>)<{({}[()]<<>({}<>)>)}{}>)}{}{<>({}<>)}{}(<>){<<<[<<<]>>>[>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.<[->.+.->+<<]>+.[-]>>]<[<<<]>>>[<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>-[<+>-[<++>-[<++>-[<+>-[<++++++++++++++>-[<++>-[<+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>-[<++>-[<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>-[<++>-]]]]]]]]]]<.>>>>]}{}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#7VcNroMgDL4OhOgJSC9COAnx7HsFFVRAQGG8RdlkUPr7FSr7MNsAwDw7QmDmyGYUoycFI3Zz3NiSLP/OTujJHhTZv7ceZk/Ih8PNEuhm@XWhm@Wbu/3KsXhUZjth/J70i8mIeZrz8mtd8HMgqZaD/zQrjvUMu6yLSfP7ztnSPlMRdT8U0E2XQgc@4V/hLa@wcLarBQEb9YD3wEj4WQTe1zCpgs5hb7Fk/W20VyudgstVsVIhKHyZJOteW5QiR@MqIJXCzZdrFEbJsUldWZKgZ3LFd1tU3zJ6Wn@Kso9YUDSMYW5qPD8CepNp/O5eeepWCWUmCEoBa3uBYt0dAOvs6YvBzyDRZ@wX6eyqeff/hyJq4kA5YK@IwBmVhHKiG10/FKnzF6gW0Ay6P0zThP2UWO2ziXNhjz3Dg10QKOCC4LhqJSbbDJUTg4iDRk1AkeZR55kgVOKckIOLqz0cLtyaAUmOb8OyMBEh0Tti1a4GuPFrMQ3aZ@2UW0blZnFZwE6tJK0VfxTnXOAjMetiuzFO28jFACMbB2BalI1iQAXSaeK5mmBAXtNt@3no8QXo7BKb5ZO28RH9Bmky8vn8AQ)

### Brain-Flak

```
(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()())(())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(())(())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(())(())(())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()())(())(())(())(())(()())(())(()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()())(()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(())(()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()())(()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()())(()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()()()()()()())(()()()()()())(()()()()()()()){({}<>)<>}<>{([({})]()<((((()()()()()){}){}){})>){({}()<({}())>){({}()<({}()())>){({}()<({}()())>){({}()<({}())>){({}()<({}((()()()){}()){})>){({}()<({}()())>){({}()<({}(((()()()){}()){}){}())>){({}()<({}()())>){({}()<({}(((()()()()())){}{}){})>){(<{}({}()())>)}}}}}}}}}}{}({}<(<>)<>{({}<>)<>}{}>)(<><>)<>{({}<>)<>}{}<>{({}[()])<>(((((()()()){}())){}{}){}())<>}{}<>(((({})(((()()())){}{}){}())))<>}{}([]){((({}[()])<{({}[()]<({}<({}<>)<>>)>)}{}>)<{({}[()]<<>({}<>)>)}{}>)}{}{<>({}<>)}{}(<>){<<<[<<<]>>>[>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.<[->.+.->+<<]>+.[-]>>]<[<<<]>>>[<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>-[<+>-[<++>-[<++>-[<+>-[<++++++++++++++>-[<++>-[<+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>-[<++>-[<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>-[<++>-]]]]]]]]]]<.>>>>]}{}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#7VgJroQgDL1OidETkCZzDsJJjGf3F1xw1EE2GZwP80VbyqMb2x8B2PHHYHrOW675e6mJdpEJQ3bTP9Sqs1aDddTv7PH7Sqdnjj5XSP5j2DwbjvRMvasFNXf8ke5ZY1KvUDV/c@VB@blQ1/JfyCSbrTEnylJPM6FRyZs//42f1v8@8Q@/6ZR75/KV3uer2@jVk9@x1rZb@Nnvf/dNcwoocV/5rN@3MucYFX8f@Ef2GbHJG6fz@edrXUws0879vOvQfXt5/l0i3UnOf28uMZ7XK9id0crv@VTY5Xgw1aroeysLy6q4vq7z2318Q9d33Nsv9rY42ZGv4hebSZ/tsesRlo1Pmy8129PNlqt8sns@HqFEpHS6lB/B59lcfV19fo/Pf4FnOznE78OZ/m/VQz9wZByp7kEQxSQwDqpspIb5D3UHJaDqHXnNeCdhRZ@GsHc@iDto8GYEdTBGcGpdewxr0VwO2iPGNf2AjHgH7kQJYJJogJ2Ky3j0OUsrAWIZuY3ILARCknawwi4DcK3XPDQqnZVSppnAdePcQFW/sBQqvXrOuaBHIqLAxrF0XLTYNV2LjeradKIlAGmQuCsStiSrq209fR7kTvhNkNgqJ9fCO9IbpY7IOI7t6w8)

The Brain-Flak might time out on TIO.

### Explanation

Coming soon.

Comment: That polyglot at the end is quite impressive...

Comment: `Explanation coming soon` -> `Jan 27`

Comment: @MDXF `Explanation coming soon` *checks date*

Comment: When you'll add an explanation?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena Soon.

Comment: @MDXF it’s already `May 5` now!

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby and Python (393 + 413 = 806 chars)

Slight change of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/298/quine-that-takes-as-input-the-name-of-a-language-and-outputs-the-same-thing-imple/312#312) of mine.  Could definitely be reduced since I just hard-coded the input without any optimisation.

#### Ruby (393 chars)

```
require 'json';s=%q[{"ruby":[" %q[","require 'json';s=##;j=JSON.load s;puts j[l='python'][1].sub('##',j[l][0].delete(' ')+s+j[l][2].delete(' '))"," ]"],"python":["' ''","import json,re;s=##;j=json.loads(s);l='ruby';print(re.sub('##',j[l][0].replace(' ','')+s+j[l][2].replace(' ',''),j[l][1],1))","' ''"]}];j=JSON.load s;puts j[l='python'][1].sub('##',j[l][0].delete(' ')+s+j[l][2].delete(' '))
```

#### Python (413 chars)

```
import json,re;s='''{"ruby":[" %q[","require 'json';s=##;j=JSON.load s;puts j[l='python'][1].sub('##',j[l][0].delete(' ')+s+j[l][2].delete(' '))"," ]"],"python":["' ''","import json,re;s=##;j=json.loads(s);l='ruby';print(re.sub('##',j[l][0].replace(' ','')+s+j[l][2].replace(' ',''),j[l][1],1))","' ''"]}''';j=json.loads(s);l='ruby';print(re.sub('##',j[l][0].replace(' ','')+s+j[l][2].replace(' ',''),j[l][1],1))
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2 to Befunge 98, <s>94</s> 78

Again, making use of Python's two ways of making strings:

Python:

```python
s='<@,kM%c%cs=%c%s%c;print s%%(39,34,39,s,39,34)%c';print s%(39,34,39,s,39,34)
```

Befunge 98:

```
<@,kM'"s='<@,kM%c%cs=%c%s%c;print s%%(39,34,39,s,39,34)%c';print s%(39,34,39,s,39,34)"
```

The python program formats the string to include itself and the characters for the single and double quote.

The Befunge program works like this:

- `<`: move to the left, and wrap around. So now we execute the commands from right to left
- `"`: make it so that every char we encounter is pushed to the stack until we encounter another `"`, so we push:

  ```
  )43,93,s,93,43,93(%s tnirp;'c%)43,93,s,93,43,93(%%s tnirp;c%s%c%=sc%c%Mk,@<'=s
  ```

  Which is actually just the python program, reversed because of the way Befunge prints (which is a pop+print loop)
- `'M`:  push `M` to the stack. `M` is also the number 77, which is one less than the number of chars pushed to the stack by the `"`s.
- `k`: pop the top value off the stack (`M`) and do the next operation that many times, plus one.
- `,`: pop the top value off the stack and print the char.
- `@`: end the program.

Comment: Good grief, and in a notoriously difficult esoteric language too. Thats..... terrifying.

Answer (score 2):

### Clipper and C (111 + 108 = 219 chars)

#### Clipper (111)

```
?'char*f="%c%cchar*f=%c%s%c;main(){printf(f,63,39,34,f,34,39,10);}%c%c";main(){printf(f,63,39,34,f,34,39,10);}'
```

#### C (108)

```
char*f="%c%cchar*f=%c%s%c;main(){printf(f,63,39,34,f,34,39,10);}%c%c";main(){printf(f,63,39,34,f,34,39,10);}
```

This is a bit of a cop-out because:

1. the "print" command in Clipper is really simple: `?'foo'` :-)
2. I based it on the "classic C" quine from http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/quine.htm, with some modification to squeeze in the `?` and `'`s.
3. I didn't `#include <stdio.h>`, so it gives a compiler warning
4. The C code output by the Clipper version had to be prodded to remove a line break that had been introduced by an 80-character column limit in either my terminal or the Harbour printing routine or something.

Comment: Well, the BASIC `PRINT` command could be abbreviated `?` as well :-)

Answer (score 2):

### [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload) and [Betaload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Betaload), 16 bytes

Underload:

```
(a(:^)*a(S)*S):^
```

Betaload:

```
((a(:^)*a(S)*S):^)S
```

Betaload is a superset of Underload, so this could be two Underload answers.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
“Ṿ;⁾v`+/ŒṘ”v`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//4oCc4bm@O@KBvnZgKy/FkuG5mOKAnXZg//8)

## [RAD](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/rad)

```
'“Ṿ;⁾v`+/ŒṘ”v`'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9yYWT//yfigJzhub474oG@dmArL8WS4bmY4oCddmAn//8)

A Jelly quine that wraps itself in single quotes, such that the resultant RAD program simply prints the original Jelly program back out.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
`:qpq`:qpq
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%3Aqpq%60%3Aqpq&inputs=&header=&footer=)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `V`

```
`\`:qpq\`:qpq`
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=V&code=%60%5C%60%3Aqpq%5C%60%3Aqpq%60&inputs=&header=&footer=)

The `V` flag does nothing, the first is a quine that unevaluates itself, and the second is a string.

Or...

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `DrV`, 16 bytes

```
`q\`:Ė\`p1→ip`:Ė
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=DrV&code=%60q%5C%60%3A%C4%96%5C%60p1%E2%86%92ip%60%3A%C4%96&inputs=&header=&footer=)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Dr`

```
0`q\`:Ė\`p1→ip`:Ė
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Dr&code=0%60q%5C%60%3A%C4%96%5C%60p1%E2%86%92ip%60%3A%C4%96&inputs=&header=&footer=)

The 0 at the start is a NOP - Vyxal pads the stack with 0s anyway, so the two programs are functionally identical.

```
`q\`:Ė\`p    `:Ė # Standard eval quine
         1→ip    # If `V` (single-char variable names) is off, this stores 1 to the variable ip.
                 # If it's on, this stores 1 to the variable i and prepends a 0 to the current program.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), 114 bytes

```scm
((lambda(v)(format #t".\\~s"(format #f" (~a~s)"v v)))"(lambda(v)(format #t\".\\\\~s\"(format #f\" (~a~s)\"v v)))")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcsxDoAgDADAr5C6tIO@qEtVUBMaE0FGvl7DgHFwveTSsnv143Yf0ZshRtF5FSyE4bxUshsyTMw1wQsBHFapiaC4QkTwl7it9vgTuU/ulcwe)

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 139 bytes

```forth
.\" ((lambda(v)(format #t\".\\\\~s\"(format #f\" (~a~s)\"v v)))\"(lambda(v)(format #t\\\".\\\\\\\\~s\\\"(format #f\\\" (~a~s)\\\"v v)))\")"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//68UoKWho5CTmJqUkapRpagCFcxNLFJRLYpT0YoCgrjhGCS6YBlJcl1hXrBmjVKZQpqkJpLHqjYHqhpoQg2JGDMKUGIQ5mkr//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python and ~-~! - 77 and 81 = 158

This Python code:

```
q=chr(124);s='@%sq=chr(124);s=%s;print(s%%repr(s))%s:';print(s%(q,repr(s),q))
```

outputs this ~-~! code:

```
@|q=chr(124);s='@%sq=chr(124);s=%s;print(s%%repr(s))%s:';print(s%(q,repr(s),q))|:
```

Can definitely be improved a lot, and adopts a whole bunch from the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript and Windows .bat, 71 bytes and 81 bytes

```
f=()=>{console.log('echo f='+(f+';f()').replace(/(?=[>^\\])/g,'^'))};f()
```

and

```
echo f=()=^>{console.log('echo f='+(f+';f()').replace(/(?=[^>^^^\^\])/g,'^^'))};f()
```