# Generate a random program in your favorite language

Tags: code-golf, generation

We all heard of testing compilers using randomly generated inputs. Your task is to write a program to generate a valid program (including no undefined behavior) in your favorite language. The generating program language doesn't have to be the same as the generated program language.

Your program will receive an integer as the argument which you can use as seed for your random number generator. The generated programs should be structurally different (given different seeds) not just different variable names or constants.

Examples:

```
$ ./generate 1
int main() { return 0; }

$ ./generate 2
#include <math.h>
int main() { return (int) pow(4, 3); }
```

Please include a couple of outputs in your answers.

The shortest solution wins. I will give a small bonus based on the number of votes, so please vote the most creative solutions.

Comment: Perfect task for developing genetic algorithms with open-ended evolution. I've always wondered how it might be done.

Comment: I think the lack of a fixed specification makes this a bad question. "Structurally different" is open to interpretation, and in some interpretations this is an extremely simple problem.

Comment: @Peter: What interpretations of 'structurally different' do you see? For example, `return 1 + (seed times) + 1` is according to rules.

Comment: `If rnd(seed) mod 2 == 0 then ';' else ''` would seem to be a valid answer. The output is Golfscript.

Comment: Not necessarily. You get the same answer for different seeds (2, 4, 6). Your set of possible programs is of size 2, while I specifically forbid that.

Comment: Where? The only restriction on the way the program depends on the seed is "The generated programs should be structurally different (given different seeds)" - which can be interpreted either as that no two seeds can give isomorphic abstract syntax trees (likely to be impractical) or that at least two seeds give non-isomorphic ASTs.

Comment: The idea was not to choose between a small set of predefined programs as per your suggestion. I understand that it is possible to get unintentional collisions, so I will not disqualify such programs. The spirit of the question is meta-programming. You are welcome to improve the question or provide some other suggestions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/587/discussion-between-alexandru-and-peter-taylor)

Comment: Seems like this would make a better code-challenge than code-golf.

Comment: All one really needs to do is golf a program that can generate a random sentence from a given BNF grammar (this is trivial).  Then just plug in the grammar for any other programming language and *poof*: a valid program in that language.  This will work for any context-free language (which unfortunately rules out Perl).

Comment: @ESultanik: Most languages, on the semantic level, are *not* context-free.  The question says "valid program (including no undefined behavior)".  Ensuring that variables are declared before use, that subscripts are in range, etc. goes beyond the definition of a context-free grammar.

Comment: @Joey: True.  I guess the method I described would just produce programs that have correct syntax.

Comment: `main(seed) { 
return 4; // Chosen by dice roll - Guaranteed to be random
}` [Reference](http://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: Neil: Just to note: Probably everyone here knows xkcd, especially the linked one. They probably also know the Dilbert one on random numbers. And it has no relevance here as it's asking for a program with random structure, not just a random number.

Comment: Target language must be Turing-complete?

Comment: Do quines but then altering the code a litte bit count?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Python → Brainf*ck (185 <strike>223</strike> <strike>233</strike> <strike>255</strike> <strike>285</strike> <strike>287</strike> <strike>303</strike> characters)

#### Code

```
import random as r,sys
r.seed(int(sys.argv[1]))
c=list('<>.,+-')+['']
n=9/r.random()
def b():
 global n
 s=''
 while n>0:n-=1;o=r.choice(c);s+=o if o else'[%s]'%b()
 return s
print b()
```

- **303 → 287 Characters**: Removed `math.ceil` (it's not really necessary).
- **287 → 285 Characters**: Switched to an empty string to denote the branch operator.
- **285 → 255 Characters**: Condensed the if statement in the while loop.
- **255 → 233 Characters**: Implemented [JBernardo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2212/jbernardo)'s suggestions from the comments.
- **233 → 223 Characters**: Implemented [tjko](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2345/tjko)'s suggestion from the comments.
- **223 → 185 Characters**: Implemented some whitespace reduction suggestions from the comments.

#### Examples

```
$ python generate.py 1
-->,,+-<<-,-<,->[[<<,[.>.<>,,>>>,.<-,+>[[<.-+[.-+.+[-,+<>-.>,++.,,-,.,<<+[+]]]]]]]]
$ python generate.py 2
[<<--+.+++>]
$ python generate.py 3
,.++<<->>[,-,+>+[,-+<-+.<[,-[+[.-,[[<<>[,+.]]]]]]]]
```

Actually figuring out what the resulting BF programs *do* is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: you can also use `if o: s+=0(NL)else: s+='['+b()+']'`

Comment: @Alexandru: Thanks!  I missed that.  Your code didn't seem to work exactly, but it helped me get it shorter.

Comment: Does this somehow mean Brainfuck is your favorite language?

Comment: @zneak: Heh, well, I've been working on a high-level language → BF compiler on-and-off for a while, so it's been on my mind.  Also, the syntax is so simple that it seemed like an easy choice for this challenge.

Comment: Not that this is a problem, but the outputted code will likely cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @Peter, true, but avoiding that using this method of random generation is likely equivalent to solving the Halting Problem!

Comment: could be `c='<>.,+-'` but will not have the empty string. `c=list('<>.,+-')+['']` is also smaller

Comment: BTW, `s+=o if o else '[%s]'%b()` is even better

Comment: @JBernardo: Thanks!  Also, the space between "else" and "'[%s]'%b()" doesn't appear to be necessary.

Comment: `import random as r,sys` saves 10 bytes.

Comment: [Simon Brown](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/337/simon-brown) proposed an edit to move the three lines inside the while loop onto one line, separated by semicolons. Also, I note that you seem to be counting tabs as 4 characters rather than 1. Given the limitations of Markdown you're probably best indenting with a single space rather than a tab.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Thanks!  IIRC, I counted the characters using `wc -c`, which must have counted the tabs that way.

Comment: Couldn't you `from random import*` and then leave off the `r` and `sys`

Comment: @Timtech: If I just needed to import `random` that would save a few bytes, but the issue is that I also need `sys` to read from `argv`, and if I convert to using `from random import *` I'd have to have a separate line to `import sys`, which requires more bytes.

Comment: @ESultanik So you can't do something like `from random,sys inport *`

Comment: @Timtech, ah, I see, I wasn't aware that that syntax worked.  I'll try it.  Thanks!

Comment: @ESultanik I'm not saying it works, but at least try it ;)

Comment: @Timtech Unfortunately that syntax doesn't work; syntax error at the comma :-(

Comment: @ESultanik Sorry about that; I hoped it would work.

Comment: If you're willing to require Python 3.7,  you can change `else'[%s]'%b()` to `else f'{b()}'` to save 2 bytes (if I counted correctly).

Comment: Very short, but it will not generate all possible programs. All loops only go deep... they are never at the same level. For instance, this program will never be generated [][]

In other words the first 50% brackets are always [ (facing right), and the last 50% brackets are ] (facing left)...  The following is one example:
[---[,.[<<[--[<..[[+<+,,.<>>>>+.<-.->-+><+.,>.-+]]]]]]]

Answer (score 17):

**Python -> Piet, <strike>385</strike> 345 char**

It's possible to generate any Piet program with this.  I could've just stopped at random pixels, but I wanted to make "interesting" programs.  The function `m` paints a pixel a color, and recursively steps into each of that pixels neighbors.  There are better ways to draw random blobs, but this is tuned to terminate in a reasonable number of steps, so it's good enough for golf.  The function `R(w,h,n)` draws *n* random blobs onto a (*w* x *h*) white image, and prints the result in PPM format.

I'm especially proud of how I generate the colors -- for a random choice of `0 <= c < 20`,

```
`[0,192,255][int(x)]`for x in'0002212220200101121100'[c:c+3]
```

is the decimal code for a valid color in the Piet palette by way of a [single-track Gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Single-track_Gray_code).  That is, each color is represented by 3 adjacent bits, and every slice `'0003...0'[c:c+3]` represents a different color.  Since this isn't the full list of 27 words on 3 letters, I really lucked out in finding the Gray code.

```
from random import*
r=randint
def R(w,h,n):
 M=[6]*h*w
 def m(x,y,c,d):M[y%h*w+x%w]=c;t=r(0,15)*(r(0,d)<2);t&8and m(x+1,y,c,d+1);t&4and m(x-1,y,c,d+1);t&2and m(x,y+1,c,d+1);t&1and m(x,y-1,c,d+1)
 while n:m(r(0,w),r(0,h),r(0,19),0);n-=1
 print"P3 %s %s 255 "%(w,h)+' '.join(`[0,192,255][int(x)]`for c in M for x in'0002212220200101121100'[c:c+3])
```

Sample output, generated by the command `R(30,40,500)`

[image: random Piet program]

Without the import, I can write it as a proper (semicolon-free) 1-liner, too:

```
import random
R=(lambda P,I,E,T:lambda w,h,n:E(w,h,I(w,h,n,lambda z,c,d,t:sum((((z,c),)*t*T(0,1)or m((z[0]+a,z[1]+b),c,d+1,T(0,d)>1)for a,b in((0,1),(1,0),(-1,0),(0,-1))),()))))(range,lambda w,h,n,m:dict(sum((m((T(0,w),T(0,h)),T(0,19),0,0)for _ in P(n)),())),lambda w,h,M:"P3 %s %s 255 "%(w,h)+' '.join(' '.join(`(x&1)*255+(x&2)*96`for x in map(int,'0001121110100202212200'[c:c+3]))for c in(M[z]if z in M else 6for z in((x,y)for y in P(h)for x in P(w)))),random.randint)
```

but it's *ridiculously* slow (and almost 100 characters longer)... though I'm not entirely sure why (and not terribly inclined to find out).

Answer (score 9):

### Python -> Python, 135 chars

```
import random,sys
random.seed(int(sys.argv[1]))
R=range(9)
print'print 1'+''.join(random.choice('+*')+'%d'%random.choice(R)for x in R)
```

Generates little random expression evaluations, like this:

```
> ./genprogram.py 1
print 1+7*2+4*7+0*3*0+6+8
> ./genprogram.py 2
print 1*8+0*6*2*5*1+3*8*4
> ./genprogram.py 3
print 1+4+5*0+7+2*4*4*1*7
> ./genprogram.py 4
print 1+0+1+3*7*1*2+0+8*7
```

Answer (score 8):

**Python -> HQ9+ : 108 chars**

```
import random
def g(): return ''.join([random.choice(['H','Q','9','+']) for x in range(random.randint(1,9))])
```

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 352 characters

Generates PHP code in PHP.

I decided I didn't care as much about length, but instead wanted an interesting and diverse set of solutions. This is my answer to that.

### Code

```
<?php mt_srand(0+$argv[1]);$r=mt_rand(1,100);$s="\$i=rand(1,$r);";while($r>0){$s.='$i';if(!($r%10))$s.='*=2;';if(!($r%9))$s.='++;';if(!($r%8))$s.='=pow($i,rand(1,$i));';if(!($r%7))$s.='--;';if(!($r%6))$s.='=substr($i,0,2);';if(!($r%5))$s.='/=2;';if(!($r%4))$s.='+=4;';if(!($r%3))$s.='*=-1;';$r-=mt_rand(1,5);}$s.='var_dump($i);';echo"<?php $s
";
```

#### Ungolfed

```
<?php
mt_srand(0+$argv[1]);
$r = mt_rand(1,100);
$s = "\$i=rand(1,$r);";
while ($r > 0)
{
    if (!($r%10)) $s .= '$i*=2;';
    if (!($r%9))  $s .= '$i++;';
    if (!($r%8))  $s .= '$i=pow($i,rand(1,$i));';
    if (!($r%7))  $s .= '$i--;';
    if (!($r%6))  $s .= '$i=substr($i,0,2);';
    if (!($r%5))  $s .= '$i/=2;';
    if (!($r%4))  $s .= '$i+=4;';
    if (!($r%3))  $s .= '$i*=-1;';
    $r -= mt_rand(1,5);
}
$s .= 'var_dump($i);';
echo "<?php $s
";
```

### Example

```
> php r.php 1
<?php $i=rand(1,58);$i*=-1;$i=pow($i,rand(1,$i));$i=substr($i,0,2);$i+=4;$i*=-1;$i=pow($i,rand(1,$i));$i=substr($i,0,2);$i+=4;$i*=-1;$i*=2;$i/=2;$i+=4;$i/=2;$i*=-1;$i*=2;$i/=2;$i=substr($i,0,2);$i*=-1;var_dump($i);
> php r.php 2
<?php $i=rand(1,57);$i*=-1;$i+=4;$i--;$i=substr($i,0,2);$i*=-1;$i*=-1;$i--;$i+=4;$i/=2;$i++;$i=substr($i,0,2);$i*=-1;$i=pow($i,rand(1,$i));$i+=4;$i--;$i=substr($i,0,2);$i+=4;$i*=-1;$i--;$i+=4;var_dump($i);
```

Comment: Could you please include an output example?

Answer (score 5):

#### scala: 1543 (scala => scala)

I have variables (x, y, z), functions (mul, add, neg, abs), values and balanced parenthesis.

```
<!--code:language-scala-->
object FormelBauer {
    val fun = List (" mul10 (", " add1 (", " neg (", " abs (")
    val ops = List (" * ", " + ", " - ", " / ")
    def c(maxLen: Int, m: Int) : String = {
        def f()= new StringBuffer (fun (r.nextInt (fun.length)))
        def w()= new StringBuffer ("" + (r.nextInt (180) - 90))
        def v()= new StringBuffer ("" + ('x' + r.nextInt (3)).toChar)
        def o()= new StringBuffer (ops (r.nextInt (ops.length)))
        def g(t: Int, b: Int, d: List [Char]) : StringBuffer ={
            var a = d.filterNot (x => if (b > 0) x == '.' else x == ')')
            if (b > m) a = a.filterNot (_ == 'k')
            if (b > m) a = a.filterNot (_ == 'f')
            if (t > maxLen) a = a.filterNot (_ == '+')
            val elem = r.nextInt (a.length)
            val start = a(elem)
            start match {
                case '.' => new StringBuffer ("")
                case 'f' => f.append(g (t + 1, b + 1, List ('(', '8', 'x')))
                case '(' => new StringBuffer ("(").append   (g (t + 1, b + 1, List ('(', '8', 'x')))
                case '8' => w.append(g (t + 1, b, List ('.', ')', '+')))
                case 'x' => v.append(g (t + 1, b, List ('.', ')', '+')))
                case ')' => new StringBuffer (") ").append  (g (t + 1, b -1, List ('.', ')', '+')))
                case '+' => o.append(g (t + 1, b, List ('f', '(', '8', 'x')))
        }}
        (g (0,0,List('f','(','8','x'))).toString
    }
import util._
  var r : Random = _    
    def main (as: Array [String]) : Unit = {
      val s=as(0).toInt
        r=new Random(s) 
        "xyz".map(c=>println("val "+c+"="+(c+r.nextInt(s))))
        println("""def mul10(i:Int)=10*i
def add1(i:Int)=i+1
def neg(i:Int)= -i
def abs(i:Int)=if(i<0)-i else i
"""+c(45,5))}
}
```

As you see, it is not very golfed. Because, it will not get me close to the other solutions, but a problem is, that more variation costs more. 3 variables, 4 functions could be easily reduced to two, for example.

Generating some samples:

```
for i in {1..7} ; do scala FormelBauer $i; echo; done

val x=120
val y=121
val z=122
def mul10(i:Int)=10*i
def add1(i:Int)=i+1
def neg(i:Int)= -i
def abs(i:Int)=if(i<0)-i else i
(y)  / 79

val x=121
val y=121
val z=123
def mul10(i:Int)=10*i
def add1(i:Int)=i+1
def neg(i:Int)= -i
def abs(i:Int)=if(i<0)-i else i
 add1 ((((78 +  neg (z * z) )  / x) ) )  + -23 - ((-83)  * y) 

val x=122
val y=123
val z=122
def mul10(i:Int)=10*i
def add1(i:Int)=i+1
def neg(i:Int)= -i
def abs(i:Int)=if(i<0)-i else i
x / -71 - (y) 

val x=122
val y=124
val z=125
def mul10(i:Int)=10*i
def add1(i:Int)=i+1
def neg(i:Int)= -i
def abs(i:Int)=if(i<0)-i else i
x

val x=122
val y=123
val z=126
def mul10(i:Int)=10*i
def add1(i:Int)=i+1
def neg(i:Int)= -i
def abs(i:Int)=if(i<0)-i else i
-24 + z

val x=121
val y=121
val z=124
def mul10(i:Int)=10*i
def add1(i:Int)=i+1
def neg(i:Int)= -i
def abs(i:Int)=if(i<0)-i else i
 abs (z) 

val x=123
val y=126
val z=126
def mul10(i:Int)=10*i
def add1(i:Int)=i+1
def neg(i:Int)= -i
def abs(i:Int)=if(i<0)-i else i
 add1 (-62 - 30 * (-68)  /  neg (x - 69 + 33 / 45 + x * x)  -  abs (-18 * (y + x)  /  neg (x)  - y)  *  abs ((61) ) )  + (y)
```

Testing the longest one:

```
add1 (-62 - 30 * (-68)  /  neg (x - 69 + 33 / 45 + x * x)  -  abs (-18 * (y + x)  /  neg (x)  - y)  *  abs ((61) ) )  + (y)
```

res6: Int = -5425

Answer (score 5):

### Perl -> shell : 66 chars

```
@p=split(':',$ENV{PATH});
@c=`ls @p[@ARGV[0]]`;
print @c[rand($#c)];
```

Possibly a little off topic, but maybe so.

```
s153254@helios:/home/s153254/lab$ perl code.p 1
telnet
s153254@helios:/home/s153254/lab$ perl code.p 2
in.rlogind
s153254@helios:/home/s153254/lab$ perl code.p 2
df
s153254@helios:/home/s153254/lab$ perl code.p 3
svenv
```

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby → Brainfuck (<strike>110</strike> 107 characters)

```
s="";m=%w:< > . , + -:;rand(99).downto(r=0){s<<(rand(40)==0? (r+=1)&&'[%s':'%s')%m.shuffle[0]};p(s<<']'*r)
```

#### Usage

```
$ ruby bf.rb
```

Produces an executable brainfuck program.

Sort of a shameless ripoff of ESultanik's, so I will credit him for the idea.

- Changed .zero? to ==0

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript -> Brainf*ck: 119 chars

```
s=prompt();a=["+","-",">","<",".",",","[-]"];i=0;b="";while(i++<s*s){b+=a[Math.floor(((Math.random()*s)%1)*7)]}alert(b)
```

Sample I/O:

```
10
.--.+,-><->.<+.[-].->.>[-][-]<+,[-]>><-[-]>,,>>[-].-+<[-]+>,<[-][-]<<[-]<[-]+,+[-][-][-].-[-],[-]>.<<[-]-..<-.->.++,>+-[-],.[-]..+,<-[-].+-[-]
11
,..[-]--,[-].,[-]>[-]->..[-]<,<..>[-]<>++-.[-].,,<[-].<+<[-]>-->[-]+-[-]+>-[-][-]>-,[-]->>-,-..++<+,,-,.,[-]->[-]<,+[-][-]+.,-,>+->.[-],.>..,++,.[-],+[-]-,.,--.--,
```

The code could definitely be shorter, but some things would, IMHO, make it less interesting. But if someone else comes up with a shorter program, I'll cut down more.

Answer (score 3):

### Python -> [Fractran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FRACTRAN) (117)

```
import random as r,sys
r.seed(int(sys.argv[1]))
z=r.randint
print','.join(`z(1,99)`+'/'+`z(1,99)`for q in[0]*z(1,99))
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Python -> Python, 148 chars

Longer than the other Python entries at the expense of being (subjectively) a little more interesting.

```
import sys as s,random as r
w,o=s.stdout.write,__builtins__
r.seed(s.argv[1])
w('print\\')
for i in'\n....':n=r.choice(dir(o));o=getattr(o,n);w(i+n)
```

This prints a deeply nested attribute of a built-in object.

```
$ python randprog.py 1
print\
round.__setattr__.__delattr__.__init__.__class__
```

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, generating PowerShell – 43

In the spirit of Keith's solution:

```
-join(0.."$input"|%{'-','+'|random;random})
```

generates random expressions of additions and subtractions:

```
PS> -join(0..(random 9)|%{'-','+'|random;random 9})
+2-0-0+3-7
PS> -join(0..(random 9)|%{'-','+'|random;random 9})
-7+1+7+1-5+2+8
PS> -join(0..(random 9)|%{'-','+'|random;random 9})
-1+7+7-0-6-0-2
PS> -join(0..(random 9)|%{'-','+'|random;random 9})
+2-6-5+3-2+7
PS> -join(0..(random 9)|%{'-','+'|random;random 9})
-6
```

Comment: A Powershell way `gcm|random -c @args|% na*` :)

Answer (score 2):

### Game Maker Language -> Arduino or Ti84-Basic, 6<sup>3</sup> characters

```
a=argument0;if a mod 2{return("void setup(){Serial.begin(9600);}void loop(){Serial.print"+string(a*random(9))+";delay("+string(floor(random(999)))+")}"}else{return(":Lbl A:Horizontal "+string(a*random(9))+":Goto A")}
```

Explanation:

`a=argument0` Puts the input into variable `a`

`if a mod 2` Basically, half the chance the program will be Arduino, half Ti-Basic 84

The Arduino program outputs random stuff at random intervals, randomly skipping random things.

The Ti-Basic Program draws horizontal lines like crazy.

Also, there is a bonus - the generated programs are already golfed! Not sure if that would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

**Perl -> HQ9+ (42 Characters)**

```
$a="HQ9+";for(1..<>%4){chop$a}print chop$a
```

Example input

```
4264532623562346
```

Output

```
Q
```

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript -> Javascript (44 characters)**

```
alert('alert("'+Math.random()*prompt()+'")')
```

And with **43** characters, it can execute the generated program instead of displaying it's source:

```
eval('alert("'+Math.random()*prompt()+'")')
```

Examples:

Seed: 5
Executed 3 times:

```
alert("2.335241624386981")
alert("0.4577956395223737")
alert("0.8359265828039497")
```

Comment: Where's the seed?