# Generate code in another language

Tags: popularity-contest, code-generation

Write a program in language A which outputs a program in language B where:

1. Language A != Language B
2. The output is itself a solution to this question.

This is a popularity contest. If you want to define your own BNFs/grammars for this, feel free, but try not to make it too boring by doing so.

EDIT: The more languages it ends up generating code in, the better (in my opinion).

EDIT2: Try to use languages that are not similar (I.e. generate the code in a different family of languages). (E.g. C to Scheme)

Comment: I would make this code-bowling, but I don't want it to be too difficult for people.

Comment: Code-bowling is not a good idea. Many solutions here would just print out larger versions on each iteration, so the arguably longest version is infinitely long.

Comment: Might want to restrict what languages. Otherwise, languages that are very similar (almost identical, such as the two Befunges) could cheat, and for some reason, such answers tend to get a lot of upvotes.

Comment: This is a slightly relaxed version of [Golf a mutual quine](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2582/194) and its variant [Write a third order quine](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4171/194).

Comment: The relaxation is that it does not need to be a "quine", that is, it can expand indefinitely. I think this is different enough to not mark it as a duplicate, but only if this is changed to make it so that it needs to be expandable (ie, never will come back to the same program, only a bigger one for each language).

Comment: Next time, remember to send your question through the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/proposed-questions-sandbox-mark-x?cb=1)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/mame/quine-relay) trumps everything

Comment: Thanks @Quincunx. I wasn't aware. Yes, yes that does user80551

Answer (score 2):

## php --> asp --> html --> xhtml .......

```
 Hello
```

Infinite languages

Comment: This is just boring: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1063/9498

Comment: @Quincunx I don't think the post you linked is about this. For example it would be boring if somebody just added the code into a variable and printed it. But in Html this is considered a code.

Comment: I know it is valid code, but it is still just hardcoding the output, and it is even easier and requires less thought.

Comment: Sorry for that I will never do it again.

Answer (score -2):

### HQ9+, HQ9++ (and more)

```
Q
```

I'm starting to like this family of languages.

Comment: [No longer funny](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1071/1490).

Comment: @Howard Sorry, I don't see how that's relevant. HQ9+ was certainly not invented by me, and wasn't invented for this task.

Comment: The question clearly said: *lang A != lang B*

Comment: @user689 HQ9+ != HQ9++