# Golfing Relay Race

Tags: code-challenge

You need to write a program in any language that will produce (source code for) a program in a different language. That program will produce a 3rd program in another language and so on.

You should aim to create many programs; you aren't limited to 3. You can re-use a language, but it won't be counted in the scoring.

Your entry is the source code of the first program, together with a list of the languages of subsequent programs produced in the order they are produced. For easy reading maybe include each program's output/source.

Scoring will be the length of the source code of the first program divided by the number of different languages used.

---

To prevent solutions such as `1` (that has been pointed out in the comments) I suggest the following extra rule:

The output of one program must not be valid code in the language of that program.

Comment: You do know that `1` is at the very least a Golfscript program that outputs a PHP program that outputs an APL program that outputs a J program that outputs a Perl program that outputs nothing, right?

Comment: Or what about this non-trivial quine version, going through 50 languages: https://github.com/mame/quine-relay

Comment: Similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/golf-a-mutual-quine

Comment: @marinus: maybe I should add a rule that states the source code produced for the next language must be invalid in the one producing it.

Comment: @marinus: I'm curious what your point is. Are you suggesting that nobody should pose a challenge which can be trivially accomplished with GolfScript? That would make most challenges moot, and render this stackexchange site pointless. Is it perhaps better to consider non-GolfScript solutions worthwhile in spite of the existence of GolfScript?

Comment: Many languages accept bare numbers as valid programs that output that number. It has nothing to do with Golfscript per se.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman, surely by definition anything which can be "trivially accomplished" isn't a challenge?

Comment: @IgbyLargeman: I was just pointing out a loophole in the question that would allow trivial answers like `1` to win, because that would make the question uninteresting. George has indeed fixed it now.

Comment: Wow. Did anyone look at the source of the quine-relay? It is even ascii art.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Clojure → C → Python 2.7 → BASIC → Bash

**Score: 13.40**

```
(println"int main(){puts(\"print'PRINT\\\"echo\\\"'\");return 0;}")
```

Here is the breakdown:

1. Clojure

   ```
   (println"int main(){puts(\"print'PRINT\\\"echo\\\"'\");return 0;}")
   ```
2. C

   ```
   int main(){puts("print'PRINT\"echo\"'");return 0;}
   ```
3. Python 2.7

   ```
   print'PRINT"echo"'
   ```
4. BASIC

   ```
   PRINT"echo"
   ```
5. Bash

   ```
   echo
   ```

---

I guess a simpler alternative would be

```
print'echo'
```

in Python 2.7, which outputs Bash code. This has a score of **5.5**, but isn't as fancy as what's above.

Answer (score 12):

My first time for that kind of challenge:

### R > Julia > BrainF**k - 91 characters - Score: 30.33

The initial R code:

```
cat("'+'^8","\"[>\"","'+'^9","'>'","'+'^13","'>'","'+'^4","'<'^3","\"-]>.>+.>+.\"",sep="*")
```

It produces the following Julia code:

```
'+'^8*"[>"*'+'^9*'>'*'+'^13*'>'*'+'^4*'<'^3*"-]>.>+.>+."
```

Which produces:

```
++++++++[>+++++++++>++++++++++++++>++++<<<-]>.>+.>+.
```

which equates to:

```
Hi!
```

in BrainF**k.

**NB:** None of the three programs is valid in any of the two other languages.