# How long is your (language) snake?

Tags: code-challenge, quine

Following on from the [third order quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4171/write-a-third-order-quine) challenge, your task is to write an [Ouroboros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouroboros) program that uses as many languages as possible.

That is, in language A, write a program pA which outputs program pB in language B. Program pB should output program pC in language C, and so on until eventually a program outputs the original program pA in language A.

No two languages in your loop can be the same or subsets or supersets of each other. **None of the programs in the loop may be identical.**

The longest chain of languages win. The length of the source code will be the tie-breaker.

Here is an example solution of length 3 given by Ventero.

```
s='print q<puts %%q{s=%r;print s%%s}>';print s%s
```

with Python generates this Perl snippet

```
print q<puts %q{s='print q<puts %%q{s=%r;print s%%s}>';print s%s}>
```

which generates the following Ruby code

```
puts %q{s='print q<puts %%q{s=%r;print s%%s}>';print s%s}
```

which then prints the original Python snippet:

```
s='print q<puts %%q{s=%r;print s%%s}>';print s%s
```

Comment: Relevant: [a 50-language "Ouroboros"](https://github.com/mame/quine-relay/).

Comment: Very similar (closed): [Create a chain of programs in different languages](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23854/create-a-chain-of-programs-in-different-languages?lq=1)

Comment: @Ypnypn It's not a duplicate of that is it? I mean this is to make the loop as long as possible with a tie-breaker of the source code length. No one has ever had the chance to post a length 4 Ouroborous before :) Also a loop is different from a chain.

Comment: It's actually [very similar to this one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12071/8478), but that didn't require the sequence to loop around, so there was no quine component.

Comment: The 50 languages beast seems to be a winner before we even started.

Comment: @kuroineko He hasn't entered it and we have no idea how he did it. I think we can safely ignore it (and it would be cheating to copy it). I suspect an entry with 4 languages would probably win here.

Comment: And did you notice that the 50-language Ouroboros is in alphabetical order?

Comment: Yusuke Endoh created a [quine of length 50!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9JVgP.png) Details and git are found here: [Quine Relay](https://github.com/mame/quine-relay)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a loop of 4 languages:

C -> Bash -> Batch -> Python -> C

C

```
main(){char *c="echo %cecho print %cmain(){char *c=%c%c%s%c%c;printf(c,34,39,92,34,c,92,34,39,34);}%c%c";printf(c,34,39,92,34,c,92,34,39,34);}
```

Bash

```
echo "echo print 'main(){char *c=\"echo %cecho print %cmain(){char *c=%c%c%s%c%c;printf(c,34,39,92,34,c,92,34,39,34);}%c%c\";printf(c,34,39,92,34,c,92,34,39,34);}'"
```

Batch

```
echo print 'main(){char *c="echo %cecho print %cmain(){char *c=%c%c%s%c%c;printf(c,34,39,92,34,c,92,34,39,34);}%c%c";printf(c,34,39,92,34,c,92,34,39,34);}'
```

Python

```
print 'main(){char *c="echo %cecho print %cmain(){char *c=%c%c%s%c%c;printf(c,34,39,92,34,c,92,34,39,34);}%c%c";printf(c,34,39,92,34,c,92,34,39,34);}'
```

Comment: Very impressive!